# exporting data from SQL query

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a SQL CmdExec Job set up to run a query however the output data contains headers, job information and total numbers of returned rows as part of the output file and I am trying to figure out how to exclude this, this project calls for only the raw data to be returned.

Based on other suggestions I've tried adding **"sqlcmd -Q set nocount on;   "** before my query as well as **"-S localhost -D master -o"** at the end of the query but the extra data remains in the results.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
sqlcmd -Q set nocount on;   
SELECT
cast(coalesce(ARMASTER.CUSTNO, ' ') as char(20)) as [CUSTNO],
cast(coalesce(ARMASTER.INVOICE, ' ') as char(20)) as [INVNO],
cast(coalesce(ITEM.PARTNO, ' ') as char(16)) as [ITEM],
cast(coalesce(ITEM.DESCRIPT, ' ') as char(65)) as [DESCRIP],
cast(coalesce(ITEM.DISRATE, ' ') as char(7)) as [DISC],
cast(coalesce(ITEM.PRICE, ' ') as char(20)) as [PRICE],
cast(coalesce(ITEM.SHIPQTY, ' ') as char(12)) as [QTYSHP],
cast(coalesce(ITEM.TOTPRICE, ' ') as char(20)) as [EXTPRICE],
cast(coalesce(ITEM.CUSERLINE, ' ') as char(10)) as [SEQNUM]

FROM ITEM
JOIN 
armaster ON ITEM.invoice = ARMASTER.invoice

ORDER BY ARMASTER.INVOICE
-S localhost -D master -o
```

Comment: Added, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use Powershell for this.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "" -Database "" -Query "" | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File ("C:\test.csv") -Force -Encoding ascii
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047946/invoke-sqlcmd-output-without-quotes-and-headers) for more information.

You can use Windows Scheduler, or SQL Agent to schedule this script. For instructions, please follow the link which you would like to implement.

SQL Agent:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/scheduling-a-powershell-script-using-sql-server-agent

Windows Agent:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/03/create-scheduled-task-for-powershell-script.html

Comment: Would this be done in SSMS with the job type set to PowerShell or are you suggesting to do it completely in PowerShell as a standalone task?

Comment: It can be both. I've changed the answer with links to instructions for both

Comment: Perfect. I've confirmed this works, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `bcp`? It is less flexible than `sqlcmd` but a standard tool to export/import data.

There are tons of `export2csv` tools which exist on the web. Download any and just set delimiter to space.

It is easy to write such exporter yourself on any language.

And of course, I can suggest my own tool: https://github.com/White-Owl/nisql